# How do I crawl an API with multiple pages

Tags: python, json, api, generator

I have an url for an API with some JSON:

```
{
  "posts": [ ... ],
  "page": { ... },
  "next": "/posts.json?page=2"
}
```

where `/posts.json?page=2` has different page numbers and might be `null` if there are no more pages.

How can I, in Python, create a function that outputs all the pages with all the posts?

I guess I will have to do something like

```
def get_posts(url, posts=[]):
  json = request(url).json()

  posts.append(json.posts)

  while json.next_page:
    return get_posts(json.next_page, posts)
```

but I guess I could do something with `yield`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_posts(url, posts=None):
  # initialize the posts lists
  posts = [] if posts is None else posts

  # make the request and convert to json
  json = request(url).json()

  # extends the posts array with the returned posts
  posts.extend(json['posts'])

  # if there is a next_page, call the function recursively
  if json.next_page:
    return get_posts(json.next_page, posts)

  # if there isn't a next_page, return the posts
  return posts
```